# How to detect whether a compiler option is supported when building a C extension?

Tags: python, distutils, python-c-extension

Is there a way to make distutils detect whether a particular compiler option is supported by the compiler?

I'm trying to fix the following bug:

https://code.google.com/p/pymssql/issues/detail?id=122

The problem is that the `-Wno-parentheses-equality` option is present in some versions of gcc but not others. I'd like to use that option for compiling C code only if the option is supported by the compiler in use.

It's just a warning disabling option, so I could remove it and it would just cause some warnings, but I'd prefer to eliminate the warnings if possible. Note that I can't correct the C code to eliminate the warnings, because the C code is generated by Cython.

Comment: Then maybe you should correct Cython.

Comment: This is a good point. That is the source of the problem.

Comment: I've inquired about fixing this in Cython: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/jxvuoIuTd7M